# How to compile Protobuf library for customised version of Eclipse on Windows 7?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

I want to compile Protobuf library for C++ on Windows 7 the only constraint I am facing is my application with which i want to bind the static lib of Protobuf, uses  .a extension of lib(the linux extension for static lib) , i am confused how to build it on Windows 7, IDE used is a customized version of eclipse!

Any help i am getting on internet is , how can i build protobuf using visual studio or vcpkg on windows platform or how to do it linux platform.

kindly help.

Comment: eclipse isn't a compiler its an IDE, your compiler is probably gcc, clang or visual c++

Comment: see the documentation at https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/README.md

Comment: Thanks , corrected it.

Comment: I have read this @AlanBirtles , not getting any help with this.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: i am using GCC compiler

Comment: Then: "To build from source using Cygwin or MinGW, follow the Unix installation instructions, above."